# How to use string::erase (it adds garbage)

Tags: c++, string, stl

I hope someone is able to help me with this.

I have some code, where I have a string variable data. data contains always something like this: "'401454654". It is always a ' with a number in the back. I want to remove the ' in the front. It is also possible, that data is an empty string. My current solution looks like this:

```
string data = /* ... */;
if(!data.empty())
    data.erase(data.begin());
else
    cout << "Error in line ...." << endl;
```

The interesting thing is, that I always get the correct string with only the number, or an empty string. But sometimes I get some weird characters plus the original '401454654 back. I really do not know, what the cause of this is.

Tested on g++ 4.6 and g++ 4.9 linaro on both windows and linux. Always the exact same result. I hope someone can give me an advice.

Comment: Can you give us a small compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I`ll post some code. It is a csv to ldif converter.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ruabmbua/3060c71cea3a07a22adb

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/QDHE53287). What input would reproduce the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that your input data contain weird characters behind the useful data? Line 33 of your code seems to assume the data are clean, which might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. I solved it by myself. I actually do not know the bug in the implementation, which I uploaded on gist, but I implemented it a second time in a far better way(For the first one I had only a few minutes time to implement it). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You might be seeing this bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60278

It's interesting though, I was able to get this to compile in gcc 4.8.1:

```
data.erase(data.begin());
```

If it is the bug you can just implement the code that it's doing under the hood:

```
copy(next(data.begin()), data.end(), data.begin());
data.pop_back();
```